# Using "a" or plural?

Tags: plural-forms, determiners

I have written a plugin that only works if the website is displaying a record page, any record page.

I have the feeling that the first version emphasis "works on all" and the second is closer to "at least on one".

Which is the best sentence:

> This extension only works on **record pages**.
>
> This extension only works on **a record page**.

Comment: *This extension is designed **for** record pages/a record page.* What do you think about it? I believe this sentence puts more emphasis on "record" - if the page qualifies as a record page, then the plugin works on it.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, though I prefer the first version with the plural.

The second could be read as "there is exactly one record page where this extension works".  I don't think anybody would actually think that, but the general form "record pages" seems to work better.

Comment: Actually, I was corrected for using the former. Though, using "record pages" is really referring to a subset of the pages. While "on a record page" seems weaker and one could argue that he tried and found a record page on which it worked.
It's like "I listened to a record" and "I listened to records". There, the difference is starling because in the first case, one understand "Oh, he listened to one of the records" and on the other, it's clear that I listened to the whole set of records. It's a bit different, though. In the end, I went with what was asked.